# Flip text on a ellipse path - Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, path, cs6

I'm having trouble flipping arched text in Photoshop CS6. All the other answers seem to use Type on a Path which I can't find in my version.

Heres what I'm trying to do, I want to flip the lorem ipsum text upside down so it reads correctly, while maintaining the proper curve:

[image]

Comment: Check out the tags--the OP is using Photoshop.

Comment: How did you create the initial curved text without text on a path? Can you just reverse the arch?

Comment: with Type on a Path I meant the menu option, the text is indeed on a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize because this isn't really an answer.  I don't believe you can do something like this in Photoshop, although because I almost never do much with text in Photoshop, I could be wrong.

Flipping text while maintaining it on a path can only be done using the Type on a Path Tool in both InDesign and Illustrator, so you are on the right track there.  However, Photoshop doesn't have the same type of Type on a Path tool as those other two programs do. Instead, you use the Horizontal Type tool on a previously created path.  Here are the instructions for CS6:  http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/photoshop/how-to-create-path-type-in-photoshop-cs6/.

I think your best bet (if possible) is create your document in either InDesign or Illustrator (depending on the rest of the content).  If you have to use Photoshop to edit the photographic portions of your image, then save the image and place it in Illustrator or InDesign and create the text in one of those two programs.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it doesnt seem possible. I chose the copout answer of simply making a bigger circle and flipping it inside

Comment: Hey, if it works...probably not a copout.  Glad you figured something out.

Answer (score 1):

To update this answer for the current functions available in Photoshop, you can easily flip type on a path in Photoshop. Simply create the type on a path in the usual way, then select the path selection tool (black arrow), hover it over the text on a path, then click and slide across it.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE, I submitted an edit to your post.  Because Stack Exchange is a compilation of years of questions and answers, there may be a lot of answers (like this one) that were correct at the time, but the software has had improvements that make other options available.  If this bothers you, please take some time to go through old posts and help us update the answers.